# PHP library for reading/writing MS Excel files?

Tags: php, excel

Is there a free PHP library for reading/writing excel files?  I don't want to use XML (I think you could read excel files as XML, I don't want to do it that way).  I also need to create graphs and other goodies, so saving the file as csv will not work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ is what you're looking for?

Comment: Although charts/graphs won't be supported in PHPExcel until the next release (mid/end February)

Comment: I did a quick check, I don't think it has functions to create graphs?

Comment: @user187809 - Unless you use .COM, then you can't get charts/graphs now with any library that I'm aware of... if you start using PHPExcel now, you'll have charts within a few weeks.

Comment: You're right, my bad. Mid/end February is quite close though, so it might be worth checking whether graph support is already in some pre-release version (a nightly build for example)?

Comment: @Mels - I know the exact state of chart/graph support in PHPExcel, because I'm the developer... and it's not available anywhere but on my test boxes at the moment. Hopefully, I'll be checking it into the SVN repository next week, once I've finished my final testing and ensuring that PHPDoc blocks all exist.

Comment: Mark Baker - Thank you, mid feb is just a few days away, I'll start using PHP Excel

Comment: Mark Baker: Wow, I didn't know you are the developer.  Your library looks very good, I'm downloading it now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the library and then use below code to read/write excel with charts :-

> http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');

/*Enable chart read on excel*/
$excel2->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
/*Enable chart read on excel*/

$excel2 = $excel2->load('excelname.xlsx'); // Empty Sheet

/*update cell data if you required */
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B6', '2');
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B7', '1');
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B8', '3');
/*-----------------------------*/

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'Excel2007');
/*Enable chart write on excel*/
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
/*Enable chart write on excel*/
$objWriter->save('excelout.xlsx');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use MS-Excel Stream Handler PHP class, which is one of the top class library for that :)

There is a great [article](https://leopathu.com/content/read-write-ms-excel-files-php) to explain how to read/write excel files through php code.